# Binding Parameters to Oracle Dynamic SQL

Tags: oracle, parameters, dynamic-sql

I have a stored procedure that accepts multiple parameters (i.e. pName, pHeight, pTeam)

I have the query built up like this:

```
SQLQuery VARCHAR2(6000);
TestCursor T_CURSOR;

SQLQuery := 'SELECT ID, Name, Height, Team FROM MyTable WHERE ID IS NOT NULL ';


-- Build the query based on the parameters passed.
IF pName IS NOT NULL
  SQLQuery := SQLQuery || 'AND Name LIKE :pName ';
END IF;

IF pHeight IS > 0
  SQLQuery := SQLQuery || 'AND Height = :pHeight ';
END IF;

IF pTeam IS NOT NULL
  SQLQuery := SQLQuery || 'AND Team LIKE :pTeam ';
END IF;


OPEN TestCursor FOR SQLQuery USING pName, pHeight, pTeam;
```

If I execute the procedure passing all parameters, it runs properly.

But if I only passed one or two of the parameters, then the procedure errors out:

```
ORA-01006: bind variable does not exist
```

How do I selectively bind the variable with the parameters based on where the parameter value was used? For example, if only pName was passed, then I would only execute the query:

```
OPEN TestCursor FOR SQLQuery USING pName;
```

Or if both pName and pTeam was passed, then:

```
OPEN TestCursor FOR SQLQuery USING pName, pTeam;
```

Hope someone can shed more ways to resolve this. Thanks.

Edit:
I could actually use the following:

-- Build the query based on the parameters passed.
    IF pName IS NOT NULL
      SQLQuery := SQLQuery || 'AND Name LIKE ''' || pName || ''' ';
    END IF;

```
IF pHeight IS > 0
  SQLQuery := SQLQuery || 'AND Height = pHeight ';
END IF;

IF pTeam IS NOT NULL
  SQLQuery := SQLQuery || 'AND Team LIKE ''' || pTeam || ''' ';
END IF;


OPEN TestCursor FOR SQLQuery;
```

But this would be VERY vulnerable to SQL Injection...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not hugely elegant but it would mean that you could always supply all three bind variables even if some of them are null. You only add the extra `WHERE` clauses if needed.

(I've tried to format the dynamic SQL to make it more readable, you could just supply it as one long string).

```
FUNCTION myFunc (
   pName   IN VARCHAR2,
   pHeight IN VARCHAR2,
   pTeam   IN VARCHAR2
)
   RETURN T_CURSOR
IS
   -- Local Variables
   SQLQuery   VARCHAR2(6000);
   TestCursor T_CURSOR;
BEGIN
   -- Build SQL query
   SQLQuery := 'WITH t_binds '||
                ' AS (SELECT :v_name AS bv_name, '||
                           ' :v_height AS bv_height, '||
                           ' :v_team AS bv_team '||
                      ' FROM dual) '||
               ' SELECT id, '||
                      ' name, '||
                      ' height, '||
                      ' team '||
                 ' FROM MyTable, '||
                      ' t_binds '||
                ' WHERE id IS NOT NULL';

   -- Build the query WHERE clause based on the parameters passed.
   IF pName IS NOT NULL
   THEN
     SQLQuery := SQLQuery || ' AND Name LIKE bv_name ';
   END IF;

   IF pHeight > 0
   THEN
     SQLQuery := SQLQuery || ' AND Height = bv_height ';
   END IF;

   IF pTeam IS NOT NULL
   THEN
     SQLQuery := SQLQuery || ' AND Team LIKE bv_team ';
   END IF;

   OPEN TestCursor 
    FOR SQLQuery 
  USING pName, 
        pHeight, 
        pTeam;

   -- Return the cursor
   RETURN TestCursor;
END myFunc;
```

I'm not in front of a workstation with DB access so I can't test the function but it should be close (please forgive any syntax errors, it's been a long day!)

Hope it helps...

Comment: Where was t_binds declared? Or do I need to declare it somewhere?

Comment: It's declared in the `WITH` clause in the SQL statement, it's a dummy table to hold the bind variables. See here: http://www.orafaq.com/node/1879

Comment: Tried this but still says ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Comment: You'll have to give me more information than "Tried this but still says ORA-01008: not all variables bound" if you want help in resolving it. I use this method myself for almost exactly the same situation and it works fine, the syntax might be a little off as my answer explains but the basic premise is sound.

Comment: I essentially executed the proc you have provided... and it says the variables are not bound.

Comment: "essentially"? What did you change?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12464/discussion-between-batuta-and-ollie)

Comment: Thanks to Ollie. Works like a charm. Although I would love to know/hear if there's any downside to this solution so as to add to my learning.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [DBMS_SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sql.htm#sthref7488) package.  This provides an alternative way to run dynamic SQL.  It is perhaps a little more cumbersome to use, but it can be more flexible, especially with varying numbers of bind parameters.

Here's how you could use it (warning: I haven't tested this):

```
FUNCTION player_search (
   pName        IN VARCHAR2,
   pHeight      IN NUMBER,
   pTeam        IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
IS 
  cursor_name   INTEGER;
  ignore        INTEGER;
  id_var        MyTable.ID%TYPE;
  name_var      MyTable.Name%TYPE;
  height_var    MyTable.Height%TYPE;
  team_var      MyTable.Team%TYPE;
BEGIN
  -- Put together SQLQuery here...

  -- Open the cursor and parse the query         
  cursor_name := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR; 
  DBMS_SQL.PARSE(cursor_name, SQLQuery, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE); 

  -- Define the columns that the query returns.
  -- (The last number for columns 2 and 4 is the size of the
  -- VARCHAR2 columns.  Feel free to change them.)
  DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(cursor_name, 1, id_var); 
  DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(cursor_name, 2, name_var, 30); 
  DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(cursor_name, 3, height_var); 
  DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(cursor_name, 4, team_var, 30); 

  -- Add bind variables depending on whether they were added to
  -- the query.
  IF pName IS NOT NULL THEN
    DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE(cursor_name, ':pName', pName);
  END IF;

  IF pHeight > 0 THEN
    DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE(cursor_name, ':pHeight', pHeight);
  END IF;

  IF pTeam IS NOT NULL THEN
    DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE(cursor_name, ':pTeam', pTeam);
  END IF;

  -- Run the query.
  -- (The return value of DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE for SELECT queries is undefined,
  -- so we must ignore it.)
  ignore := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(cursor_name); 

  -- Convert the DBMS_SQL cursor into a PL/SQL REF CURSOR.
  RETURN DBMS_SQL.TO_REFCURSOR(cursor_name);

EXCEPTION 
  WHEN OTHERS THEN 
    -- Ensure that the cursor is closed.
    IF DBMS_SQL.IS_OPEN(cursor_name) THEN 
      DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(cursor_name); 
    END IF; 
    RAISE; 
END;
```

(Note: [`DBMS_SQL.TO_REFCURSOR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sql.htm#CHDFDCDE) is new in Oracle 11g.)

Comment: +1, I like using DBMS_SQL as it's more "supported" but a bit more involved than the method I suggested.

Answer (score 1):

The approach I use is to include in the dynamic SQL an ELSE case the states the reverse of the IF. Your code tests that pName is not null, so I would add a clause to the generated query testing that pName IS Null. That way you can pass the same parameters every time without affecting the results of the query.

```
SQLQuery VARCHAR2(6000);
TestCursor T_CURSOR;

SQLQuery := 'SELECT ID, Name, Height, Team FROM MyTable WHERE ID IS NOT NULL ';


-- Build the query based on the parameters passed.
IF pName IS NOT NULL  
  SQLQuery := SQLQuery || 'AND Name LIKE :pName ';
ELSE 
  SQLQuery := SQLQuery || 'AND :pName IS NULL';
END IF;

IF pHeight IS > 0
  SQLQuery := SQLQuery || 'AND Height = :pHeight ';
ELSE
  SQLQuery := SQLQuery || 'AND :pHeight <=0 ';
END IF;

IF pTeam IS NOT NULL
  SQLQuery := SQLQuery || 'AND Team LIKE :pTeam ';
ELSE
  SQLQuery := SQLQuery || 'AND :pTeam IS NULL';
END IF;


OPEN TestCursor FOR SQLQuery USING pName, pHeight, pTeam;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SQLQuery := 'SELECT ID, Name, Height, Team FROM MyTable WHERE ID IS NOT NULL ';

SQLQuery := SQLQuery || 'AND Name LIKE :pName ';
SQLQuery := SQLQuery || 'AND Team LIKE :pTeam ';
SQLQuery := SQLQuery || 'AND (Height = :pHeight OR :pHeight = 0)';

OPEN TestCursor FOR SQLQuery USING nvl(pName, '%'), nvl(pTeam, '%'), nvl(pHeight, 0), nvl(pHeight, 0);
```

?

Comment: like '%' doesnt affect null. so if some of these fields is null, u will get false