# Repeating the same bind variable multiple times when using the OPEN...FOR dynamic SQL structure in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

This is a follow on question to Vincent Malgrat's [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230428/executing-a-dynamic-sql-statement-into-a-sys-refcursor#2230740). I can't find the correct syntax to use when you need to use the same bind variable multiple times when using `OPEN...FOR` dynamic SQL. You can see the syntax for `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/dynamic.htm#LNPLS01108) (see "Using Duplicate Placeholders with Dynamic SQL") … but not for `OPEN...FOR`. Does the syntax differ with duplicate placeholders when using `OPEN...FOR`? I'm using Oracle 12c. This is in a PL/SQL package not an anonymous block.

For example, this example from Oracle's own documentation works fine:

```
DECLARE
   TYPE EmpCurTyp IS REF CURSOR;
   emp_cv   EmpCurTyp;
   emp_rec  emp%ROWTYPE;
   sql_stmt VARCHAR2(200);
   my_job   VARCHAR2(15) := 'CLERK';
BEGIN
   sql_stmt := 'SELECT * FROM emp WHERE job = :j';
   OPEN emp_cv FOR sql_stmt USING my_job;
   LOOP
      FETCH emp_cv INTO emp_rec;
      EXIT WHEN emp_cv%NOTFOUND;
      -- process record
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE emp_cv;
END;
/
```

But if you need to reference the `:j` bind variable more than once, how do you do it in a case like this where `:j` is referenced twice?

```
sql_stmt := 'SELECT * FROM emp WHERE (job = :j AND name = :n) OR (job = :j AND age = :a)' ;
```

I have tried

```
OPEN emp_cv FOR sql_stmt USING my_job, my_name, my_age;
```

and

```
OPEN emp_cv FOR sql_stmt USING my_job, my_name, my_age, my_job;
```

and in both cases it gives this error:

```
ORA-01008: not all variables bound
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the parameter twice in the USING clause:

```
 OPEN emp_cv FOR sql_stmt USING my_job, my_job;
```

Here's your example, but simplified:

```
DECLARE
   TYPE EmpCurTyp IS REF CURSOR;
   emp_cv   EmpCurTyp;
   emp_rec  varchar2(10);
   sql_stmt VARCHAR2(200);
   my_job   VARCHAR2(15) := 'X';
BEGIN

   OPEN emp_cv FOR 'select * from dual where dummy = :j or dummy = :j' 
    USING my_job, my_job;
   LOOP
      FETCH emp_cv INTO emp_rec;
      EXIT WHEN emp_cv%NOTFOUND;
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE emp_cv;
END;
```

Comment: Only when using an anonymous block repeated placeholder are possible: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/dynamic.htm#LNPLS01108

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have updated my question as it wasn't clear that I am not in an anonymous block, but rather in a PL/SQL package.

Comment: Also, I did actually try that and it gives me ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Comment: @JDor: I copy/pasted this example on livesql.oracle.com and I didn't get an `ORA-01008`. Either as an anonymous block or inside a procedure (db version 19c)

Comment: I think as usual I over-complicated things here. My own actual code was far too complex to use in the question, as it builds up a huge SQL string. After reading your comment, I stripped my own code down to the bare minimum, and it worked as you say by repeating the binds. When I added back in the full code, the problem returned. I think it may be a combination of comments in the code and the way I'm building the string. Bizarre. See other people with similar problems in the answers to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493028/ora-01008-not-all-variables-bound-they-are-bound

Answer (score 2):

Repeated placeholders topic is well described here https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/dynamic.htm#LNPLS631 . In a word, in **USING** clause parameters are treated by positions, so you can use variable several times in a query but for each occurrence a separate value must be provided in **USING** statement.

Comment: Thanks but as I said in my question, that documentation has the syntax for EXECUTE IMMEDIATE but not for OPEN...FOR, which appears to be different

Comment: I did actually try that and it gives me ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Comment: @JDor could you please reproduce that behavior in Oracle Live Sql? because i can’t

Comment: Thanks. I actually can't reproduce the problem as my actual code is an enormous legacy procedure that conditionally concatenates a huge string containing the dynamic SQL.I think have fallen victim to the "comments" issue described by people here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493028/ora-01008-not-all-variables-bound-they-are-bound

Answer (score 0):

We can try this instead of passing param_val N times the parameter is required in the query
For eg: I will modify the query like this

```
sql_stmt := 'SELECT * FROM emp, (select :j j_type from dual) temp WHERE (job = temp.j_type AND name = :n) OR (job = temp.j_type AND age = :a)';
```

And pass my_job value only once as shown below:

```
OPEN emp_cv FOR sql_stmt USING my_job;
```

In this way we could pass all such parameters in a single select query joined to the main table. For N parameters, this is how the query looks like:

```
(select :param1 param1, :param2 param2, ....., :paramN paramN  from dual) temp

OPEN cursor FOR sql_stmt USING param1,param2, ...., paramN;
```